# Tensorflow choice of values of variables after training

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, weights

I am trying to build a neural network, that is able to perform a linear regression. After for example 1000 epochs, I encountered the situation, where the smallest loss-value was not the last loss-value of my training.

1. After 800 epochs I reached a loss of 17000.
2. After 1000 epochs I found a loss of 19000.

I guess, that Tensorflow does not use the weights of the smallest loss but of the latest loss.

Is there a way to tell Tensorflow to use the weights of the smallest loss instead?

Comment: Your question is better suited for Stack Overflow. [Here's something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186330/save-model-weights-at-the-end-of-every-n-epochs) that might help. Still, training is not only about searching for optimal parameters, it's also about stability of such parameters. If your model did not converge yet, whatever you found at the 800th epoch might just be a local minima and such small loss a result of overfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen that a neural network model gets worse results on a holdout set after a certain point. This is related to [overfitting](/questions/tagged/overfitting). The fix is easy: just save the model after each epoch. If the new model is worse, don't save it. Then when you want to make predictions, load the best model.